# What does "to look for most is a..." mean in this passage? Is it correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does the sentence in bold mean? Is that correct sentence? If not, please, write with other words. Text:

> Most students ask teachers, club advisors, coaches, and mentors.
>   To get the best letters possible, make sure you identify people who are supportive of you. When you ask them, let them know where you are applying and why. The goal is to choose someone who will stress the strengths you have already highlighted, or provide an opportunity to add something new about you that the admissions officer does not yet know.
>   It definitely has an impact. You should always pay attention to your grades, especially those in your junior year of high school. But don't fret. **What universities look for most is an upward trend, someone who is constantly getting better and improving.**
>   If there is an unexpected event that caused your grades to drop, that will also be taken into consideration. And, if you have only done well in a particular subject, you can highlight that strength, stressing that you will use college as a way to really hone in and excel at your strengths and your passions.

Comment: Do you understand what “look for” means there or is the problem “most”?

Answer (score 2):

> What universities look for most is an upward trend, someone who is constantly getting better and improving.

This sentence is correct. It may be easier to understand if I rearrange it a little bit:

> An upward trend is what universities look for most. In other words, universities look for someone who is constantly getting better and improving.

Or, in other words: universities think that improvement is the most important thing.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a rephrasing:

While it'd be nice if you had good grades throughout school, universities' top priority is overall improvement over time, meaning that bad grades at the beginning that consistently improve to good grades by the end are quite acceptable.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least tell me why. Even better, provide your own translation.

Comment: The rephrasing seems to be good, but it would have been more helpful if you'd also explained how the original phrasing works.